# AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI does not prompt to create new keypair

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following this AWS tutorial to deploy python application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-common-steps.html#python-common-configuring

I've followed the guide up to a point where EB Cli should prompt me to create a keypair. But all I got is a prompt to type keypair name.

```
Do you want to set up SSH for your instances?
(y/n): y

Type a keypair name.
(Default is aws-eb):
You must specify a key type (-t).
Usage: ssh-keygen [options]
Options:
  -b bits     Number of bits in the key to create.
  -c          Change comment in private and public key files.
  -e          Convert OpenSSH to IETF SECSH key file.
  -f filename Filename of the key file.
  -g          Use generic DNS resource record format.
  -i          Convert IETF SECSH to OpenSSH key file.
  -l          Show fingerprint of key file.
  -p          Change passphrase of private key file.
  -q          Quiet.
  -y          Read private key file and print public key.
  -t type     Specify type of key to create.
  -B          Show bubblebabble digest of key file.
  -C comment  Provide new comment.
  -N phrase   Provide new passphrase.
  -P phrase   Provide old passphrase.
  -r hostname Print DNS resource record.
  -G file     Generate candidates for DH-GEX moduli
  -T file     Screen candidates for DH-GEX moduli
ERROR: The EB CLI cannot find your SSH key file for keyname "aws-eb". Your SSH key file must be located in the .ssh fold
er in your home directory.
```

I also tried

```
eb init --interactive
```

but the result is still the same.

I also dig up EB CLI doc here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html

the result I should get is something like this:

```
Select a keypair.
1) [ Create new KeyPair ]
(default is 1): 1
```

I'm on Windows 8.1 using Powershell.

My Eb Cli version is:
EB CLI 3.4.5 (Python 2.7.1)

I've installed OpenSSH and everything you saw in the AWS tutorial(the link above) up to that point.

I'll provide as much information as I can. Please feel free to ask.

I've been stuck with this for a while trying a lot of options.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you actually *created* a key-pair? I.e. did you run ssh-keygen or have you used the AWS console (under EC2:Network&Security:Key pairs) to create one?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I haven't created a keypair yet. The step in question should allow me to create one but I'm stuck like above explanation. But thanks to your response I'll look into other means of creating keypair. I'll try it tomorrow and will post the result. ;)

Comment: Got it woked by manually creating keypair using EC2 console. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your ssh-keygen file doesn't have the same flags that the CLI expects (and uses). Any idea what version on ssh you have installed?

Answer (score 9):

Got it woked by manually creating keypair using EC2 console.

Here's how to do it for those who're interested:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair

Thanks SonarJetLens for your guidance. :)

Comment: what was the name of the keyfile? I've added the EC2 key pair but I'm receiving `ERROR: NotFoundError - The EB CLI cannot find your SSH key file for keyname` even though I've placed the downloaded key file in `~/.ssh`

Comment: @anon58192932 did you figure this out?

Comment: I don't remember the solution unfortunately as it was at my last company / project.